# Search for a particular pattern and replace any word or line above it with a new pattern

Tags: vim, awk, sed

Suppose I have the following sentence:

```
jack and jill
climbs up a hill
```

I want to search for `hill` in file and replace `jill` by `jerry`, i.e, the line above it while `hill` remains as it is. Is it possible using the vim editor or awk/sed?

Comment: yes it is possible to do it with vim, sed and awk... what this forum expects is for you to make an attempt to solve it yourself and explain/show how it fails... see https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: using vim, a simple `:g/hill/-1s/jill/jerry` would suffice

Answer (score 5):

With GNU sed:

```
sed 'N;/\n.*hill/s/jill\(.*[^\n]\)/jerry\1/' file
```

- `N`: appends next line to pattern space
- `/\n.*hill/`: if `hill` is found after new line
- `s/jill\(.*[^\n]\)/`: replace `jill` found before new line and following captured characters
- `jerry\1`: with `jerry` string followed with captured characters

To edit the file *in place*, try the `-i` flag:

```
sed -i 'N;/\n.*hill/s/jill\(.*[^\n]\)/jerry\1/' file
```

Comment: As far as I can tell, all other solutions assume the terms are on the same line, which they aren't.

Comment: `^1` thanks for informing me, I could not make out without codetags !

Comment: @BenjaminW. Multiline input was not visible without proper formatting.

Comment: I know, I'm pointing out that all other solutions are not addressing the actual question. Also, everybody can edit the question, as you did.

Answer (score 3):

**Basic syntax for find and replace**

**Sed**

```
sed 's/word_to_find/word_to_replace/g' inputfile
```

To update file pass the `-i` option

```
sed -i 's/word_to_find/word_to_replace/g' inputfile
```

**gawk**

```
gawk -i inplace '{gsub(/find/,"replace"); print}' inputfile
```

**awk**

write to somefile and then rename it

```
awk '{ gsub(/find/,"replace"); print }' inputfile >outputfile
```

Shortcut `1` at end end does default operation print current record/row/line

```
awk 'gsub(/find/,"replace") + 1' inputfile >outputfile
```

-- edit --

**Results**

```
$ cat f
jack and jill
climbs up a hill

$ awk '/hill/{gsub(/jill/,"jerry",prev);h=0;if(prev)print prev;print;prev="";next} h{print prev} {prev=$0; h=1}' f
jack and jerry
climbs up a hill
```

**Better Readable**

```
   awk '/hill/{
               gsub(/jill/,"jerry",prev);
               h=0;
               if(prev)print prev;
               print;
               prev="";
               next
         }
        h{
               print prev
         }
         {
               prev=$0; h=1
         }
     ' f
```

**Tested with**

**Input**

```
$ cat f
jack and jill
climbs up a hill

jack and jill
climbs up a a
climbs up a hill

climbs up a a
climbs up a hill
jill
climbs up a hill
climbs up a hill
```

**Output**

```
$ awk '/hill/{gsub(/jill/,"jerry",prev);h=0;if(prev)print prev;print;prev="";next} h{print prev} {prev=$0; h=1}' f
jack and jerry
climbs up a hill

jack and jill
climbs up a a
climbs up a hill

climbs up a a
climbs up a hill
jerry
climbs up a hill
climbs up a hill
```

Comment: To be more exact, if I understood correctly `sed '/hill/ s/jill/jerry/'`

Comment: `jill` and `hill` are not on the same line.

Answer (score 2):

try following:

**Solution 1st:** Where I am considering you have to substitute only first occurrence of jill.

```
awk '/hill/{sub(/jill/,"jerry")}1'  Input_file
```

**Solution 2nd:** Where I am considering that you have to substitute all occurrences of jill.

```
awk '/hill/{gsub(/jill/,"jerry")}1'   Input_file
```

**Solution 3rd:** If you want to save this new change into Input_file itself then following may help in same.(place sub/gsub in order to replace one/multiple occurrences of string)

```
awk '/hill/{sub(/jill/,"jerry")}1'  Input_file > temp_Input_file && mv temp_Input_file  Input_file
```

**EDIT:** Above solutions will work when strings jill and hill are on same line, after EDIT of OP's post seems these strings are not on same line, so following could be helpful then.

```
awk '/jill/{val=$0;getline;if($0 ~ /hill/){sub(/jill/,"jerry",val);print val ORS $0};next} 1'   Input_file
```

Answer (score 2):

In awk, considering `hill` and `jill` are whole words, not parts of longer strings. First, some test data:

```
jack and jill
climbs up a hill
then jill silly
saws a hillbilly
cookin them jills
on a prec- hill
```

Code:

```
$ awk '
/(^| )hill( |$)/ {                 # when a field is "hill"
    n=split(p,a)                   # split previous record p to a
    for(i=1;i<=n;i++) {            # for each word
        sub(/^jill$/,"jerry",a[i]) # replace jill with jerry
        p=(i==1?"":p OFS) a[i]     # use p as buffer to reconstruct record
    }
}
{
    if(NR>1)                       # don t print on the first record
        print p                    
    p=$0                           # store record to p
}
END {
    print                          # output the last record as-is
}' file
jack and jerry
climbs up a hill
then jill silly
saws a hillbilly
cookin them jills
on a prec- hill
```

Answer (score 2):

Using vim this could be as simple as

```
:g/hill/-1s/jill/jerry
```

**Breakdown**

```
:g                  starts a global command
/hill               searches for hill
/-1                 set the range to the previous line
s/jill/jerry        substitute jill with jerry
```

**Misc**

- if there are more `jill`'s on a previous line to be substituted, just add `/g`
- if you only want to match whole words, use `\<jill\>`
- ...

Answer (score 1):

From Linux.com:

[Vim tips: The basics of search and replace](https://www.linux.com/learn/vim-tips-basics-search-and-replace)

> When you want to search for a string of text and replace it with another string of text, you can use the syntax :[range]s/search/replace/. The range is optional; if you just run :s/search/replace/, it will search only the current line and match only the first occurrence of a term.
>
> Most of the time, that's not sufficient, so you can add a range like so:
>
> :8,10 s/search/replace/g
>
> In that example the range is from line 8 to line 10. I've also added the "global" option, which tells Vim to replace every occurrence on a line, and not just the first occurrence. Without adding g, your search will match only the first instance of a string in any given line.
>
> Another way to specify the range is to enter visual mode and select the lines that you want to search, and then press : to enter command mode. To enter visual mode from normal mode, press v to select regular visual mode, or V for line selection, or Ctrl-v for block selection. Then select the range in visual mode and press :, followed by the search command you wish to use.
>
> If you want to search an entire file, you can use % to indicate that as the range:
>
> :%s/search/replace/g

---

You can also use sed if you are so inclined, that question has already been answered [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/159367/using-sed-to-find-and-replace).

Answer (score 1):

Why not Perl?

```
perl -ne '$last =~ s/jill/jerry/ if(/hill/); print $last; $last = $_; END { print $last;}' file
```

Slightly more readable version:

```
$last =~ s/jill/jerry/ if($_ =~ /hill/);
print $last;
$last = $_;
END {
    print $last;
}
```